# UIVisualEffectView's subviews not shown in XCUIApplication().debugDescription

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xcuitest

I have a `UIVisualEffectView` with 2 subviews added in the UIVisualEffectView's `contentView`. This works fine when running normally, but when I try to add UI Test to check that the correct subviews are added, `XCUIApplication().debugDescription` does not show the UIVisualEffectView's subviews - it only shows the `UIVisualEffectView`.